# Any way to extract the current subtitle line from MPlayer

Tags: mplayer

Is there any way to copy the current subtitle line to the clipboard or direct it into a different app? For example, while MPlayer is paused extract the line that is currently on the frame and send it into Goldendict. A method that takes minimum actions, a shortcut key, for instance, would be great or selecting subtitles on the screen with a mouse. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No. [This](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/subosd.html) is all you can do with subtitles and extracting them. Depending in the type of file you can use:

```
MPsub: -dumpmpsub
SubRip: -dumpsrtsub
MicroDVD: -dumpmicrodvdsub
JACOsub: -dumpjacosub
Sami: -dumpsami
```

There are some more on that site but all will extract all lines and not just the current line.

So to get a specific line you need to extract the subtitles to a text file. Examine the text file, locate the timestamp you need and the copy/paste the line. It can be automated to an extent but getting the timestamp to find the line is manual work.

Comment: But I already have the subtitle file and can find current line in it. The idea is different and it's even faster to type a few words. Basically I want to find an instant way to transfer words from subtitles that currently on the screen to Goldendict.